# POST by Angular to server (Which is written in Node Express) not recognize parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm new to Node Express, so sorry if I'm asking silly question.
I'm designing an application that consists of two parts 1- Server side 2- Client side. 
These two parts are completely independent. I run the server side on localhost:3000 and I run the client side on localhost:9000. I am trying to POST to the server side via client application but the response I got from server shows that it cannot recognize my POST parameters. here is the response that I expect :

```
{
  "make": "Toyota",
  "model": "Corolla",
  "year": "2013"
}
```

Here is the response that I get currently:

```
{
  "{\"make\":\"Toyota\",\"model\":\"Corolla\",\"year\":\"2013\"}": ""
}
```

When I post via the server User Interface, it responds correctly but when I try to post with client side app, it doesn't recognize the parameters.

Here are the code that I wrote:

1- Server Side Code

**app.js:**

```
'use strict';

/*
 * Express Dependencies
 */
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

/*
 * Use Handlebars for templating
 */
var exphbs = require('express3-handlebars');
var hbs;

// For gzip compression
app.use(express.compress());
//Middleware to parse the request body
app.use(express.urlencoded());

/*
 * Config for Production and Development
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set the default layout and locate layouts and partials
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        layoutsDir: 'dist/views/layouts/',
        partialsDir: 'dist/views/partials/'
    }));

    // Locate the views
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/dist/views');

    // Locate the assets
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/assets'));

} else {
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
        // Default Layout and locate layouts and partials
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        layoutsDir: 'views/layouts/',
        partialsDir: 'views/partials/'
    }));

    // Locate the views
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

    // Locate the assets
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
}

// Set Handlebars
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');



/*
 * Routes
 */
// Index Page
app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    response.render('index');
});


app.post('/command', function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        console.log(request.body.make);
        console.log(request.body.model);
        console.log(request.body.year);

        response.send(request.body);
    // ...
});

/*
 * Start it up
 */
app.listen(process.env.PORT || port);
console.log('Express started on port ' + port);
```

**index.handlebars**

```
<div class="container">

    <form action="command" method="post">

    <label>Make</label>
    <input type="text" name="make" id = "make" value="" />
    <br />
    <label>Model</label>
    <input type="text" name="model" id = "model" value="" />
    <br />
    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="text" name="year"  id = "year" value="" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

</div>
```

2- Client Side

**service.js**

```
myAppServices.factory('postServices', function($http, $q, $rootScope){
    var dataArray = [];
    var sendPost = function(selectedMake, selectedModel, selectedYear){

    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http({
            method:'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/command',
        data: {
          make:selectedMake, 
          model:selectedModel, 
          year:selectedYear
        },

        headers : {
                   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
             }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              defer.resolve(data);
              // $rootScope.$broadcast('UPDATE_RESULT_TABLE', data);
              dataArray.push(data);

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Fail");
                defer.reject({});
            });

    return defer.promise;
}

return {
    dataArray: dataArray,
    sendPost: sendPost
    }
});
```

**controller.js**

```
myAppControllers.controller('postCriteria', function($scope, $http, postServices, $location) {
    //We define the following line to get the values from child and put it to parent
    $scope.carData = {car:'', Model:'', Year:''};

    $scope.searchCar = function  () {
      postServices.sendPost($scope.carData.car, $scope.carData.Model, $scope.carData.Year).then(function(data){
                        $location.path('/results');
                });
        }         
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your response is correct, it's just the serialized version, forced into a key/value pair that doesn't quite work.  HTTP does not support sending non-serialized data in a request body.  If you modify the last line in your server code to:

```
response.send(JSON.parse(request.body));
```

I think you should get the response you want.

Comment: When I post via the server form, it responds correctly but when I try to post with client side app, it doesn't recognize the parameters. BTW I changed that line on code and it crashed the server side because it's already a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use express [json.response function](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json)

Something like this:

```
res.json(200, JSON.parse(request.body));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AngularJS sends POST data as JSON data:

[image: POST data]

I can see two solutions:

- Use `params` instead of `data` in `$http` method. In this case your object will be sent in URL as GET parameters, not in a request body, and thus you will have to write `response.send(request.query);` instead of `response.send(request.body);` on the server
- You can perform POST data by passing a string instead of object. With jQuery it may be done as easy as writing:

```
$http({
    ...
    data: $.param({make:'Toyota',model:'Corolla',year:'2013'})
    ...
});
```

If you don't mind using jQuery, the second variant is more preferable as for me :)